# Using Navigation drawer in ScrollView

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_cardView01"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_cardView01"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
            <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_button_script"
        android:text="@string/script_btn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/main_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_script"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_button_addOn"
        android:text="@string/addOn_btn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/main_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_addon"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_cardView01"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_cardView01"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_button_map"
        android:text="@string/map_btn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/main_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_map"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_button_skin"
        android:text="@string/skin_btn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/main_button"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_skin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_button_texturePack"
        android:text="@string/tp_btn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/main_button"
                android:background="@drawable/main_button_texturepack"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_button_help"
            android:text="@string/help_btn"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/main_button"
            android:background="@drawable/main_button_help"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_top10_cardView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_top10_cardView"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top10"
        android:text="Top 10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_top10_cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/cardview">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_top10_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/suggested"
        android:text="Suggested"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_suggested_cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/cardview">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_suggested_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ID00010bREDSTONE"
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/USER_redstone"
            android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/New"
        android:text="New"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/cardview">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_new_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_relativeLayout03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_CS_cardView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_CS_cardView"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CS"
        android:text="Coming Soon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_CS_cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/cardview">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_CS_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_new_cardView"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updated"
        android:text="Updated"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_updated_cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/cardview">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_updated_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|center"
    android:text="test"/>
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to add Navigation Drawer in my project. My source looks like the first one and second one is navigation drawer, but when I try to add navigation drawer, either only Navigation Drawer shows up or only scrollview show up.

However what I want to do is using Navigation drawer and ScrollView together(not scrollView inside Navigation drawer)

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. Please give me more info.

Comment: I just want to use Navigation Drawer inside ScrollView or something like that. When I try to use them together, either only Navigation Drawer shows up or only scroolview shows up

Comment: NavigationDrawer AND ScrollView can work, but Navigation Drawer IN a Scroll view is not possible (and does not really mage sense to me)

Comment: Like Google play store, it has both Navigation Drawer and ScrollView. That's what i meant, sorry for any confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use navigation drawer as direct child of root view for your activity and add another fragment or layout for your own code(scroll view).Also , it is mandate that while using Nav Bar, the root view should contain only two direct views.

Comment: MainActivity{ LinearLayout(RootView){ DrawerLayout(NavigationDrawer) {}  LinearLayout{ ScrollView{} } } } Only navigation drawer shows up(when navigation drawer is removed, scrollview will be show up again.

Comment: Try this and refer to google documentation. <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent">     <!-- The main content view -->     <scrollview android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="match_parent" />     <!-- The navigation drawer -->     <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"         android:layout_width="240dp"         android:layout_height="match_parent"         android:layout_gravity="start"

Comment: isn't that using scrollView in Navigation drawer?

Comment: I think you are confusing between navigation drawer and navigation layout.

Comment: Use that and let me know whether it is working or not. I have recently worked on this. I can be wrong but the above code worked for me.

Comment: So do I use that one and just put my original source in <!- The main content view--> ?

Comment: Yes , whole content inside scroll view